# Адаптивный svg, чтобы уменьшался пропорционально div (экрану)

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Что я только не перепробовала, но то ли не вижу какой то мелочи, то ли не понимаю сути.

Есть svg с небольшой анимацией:

```
<svg version="1.0" id="_x31_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 122 263;"> 
<path id="dlin" fill="none" stroke="#000000" x="10" y="10"
stroke-dasharray="344" stroke-dashoffset="344" 
 d="M8,260.9 8,24.4 115.8,24.4 ">
 <animate id="dlin1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" fill="freeze" values="344;0"/> 
</path>  
 <text id="dlin2" fill="none" stroke="none" x="20" y="20"   style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:14">
ПРИВЕТ 
<animate id="filldlin2" dur="1s" begin="dlin1.end"  repeatCount="1"
 attributeName="fill"   values="#1c83b3;#000000" fill="freeze" />
 </text> 
 </svg>
```

Он вставлен в на страницу в необходимый div вот таким образом

```
<div><object id="linii" type="image/svg+xml" data="test1.svg" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></object> </div>
```

При уменьшении размера экрана div  уменьшается, как надо, а вот svg - нет.
Мне очень надо, чтобы он уменьшался пропорционально div по сути экрану, причем плавно, так как на фоне картинка и она уменьшается плавно..
Я понимаю, что я не знаю какой-то основы, ведь если я задам мега маленькие размеры этому div я вижу, что он просто режет svg.

Comment: во viewBox уберите точку с запятой то есть оставьте просто цифры

Comment: Заверните всю эту конструкцию в div

Comment: @MaximLensky Спасибо большое!! Такая мелочь а портила мне жизнь)) Теперь все работает!